# Cannot access function from within module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

Im writing some [Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/) tests and I want to have a helper function at the top of a file accessible to all tests within it. I have:

```
'use strict';

var _this = this;


this.commonHelper = function(browser) {
    //do something
};

module.exports = {

    'Some Test': function(browser) {

        console.log('_this is ', _this);

        _this.commonHelper(browser)
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'commonHelper'
```

Yet the output from the console.log is:

```
_this is  { commonHelper: [Function] }
```

So the error makes no sense because `_this` contains the `commonHelper` function. Any ideas?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem. http://ideone.com/KWOQUB

Comment: Actually turns out I had a typo in my code, which I hadn't included in sample code above. Stupid me

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.